# Require Java 8 to build Scala project using Maven

Tags: scala, maven, java-8, scala-maven-plugin

I'm using `scala-maven-plugin` to build a Scala project using Maven. My project depends on some libraries from Java 8. I would like to specify in my pom that the project requires Java 8 (using something akin to `-target=jdk-1.8`, which appears not to exist) so that it will fail a little more elegantly/informatively when someone tries to compile using Java version < 8. Currently it just fails to find the packages I'm trying to import.

I tried adding `maven-compiler-plugin` with `source` and `target` set to 1.8, and this didn't work, presumably because `scala-maven-plugin` is handling compilation instead of `maven-compiler-plugin`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: I have, it doesn't work, presumably because scala-maven-plugin handles the compilation (I don't even have the maven-compiler-plugin in my original pom). Thanks for pointing this out, I'll add it to my question.

Comment: http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#jvmArgs

Comment: @cchantep I tried setting `-target 1.8` and `-source 1.8` via `jvmArgs`, and it did nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Maven Enforcer Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) to enforce some rules to be asserted when running your Maven build.

Here you want to make sure that the `Java` version used is at least `8`. You can achieve this by adding the following to your `pom.xml` file:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>enforce-java</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>enforce</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <rules>
              <requireJavaVersion>
                <version>[1.8,)</version>
              </requireJavaVersion>
            </rules>    
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```